# jquery merge 2 arrays deep recursive

Tags: jquery, arrays, merge

Is it possible in jquery to merge those to arrays together?

```
[["add", ["image", ["to", ["title", ["published", undefined]]]]]]
[["add", ["text", ["to", ["title", ["published", undefined]]]]]]
```

to get this one?

```
["add",
    ["image", ["to", ["title", ["published", undefined]]]]
    ["text", ["to", ["title", ["published", undefined]]]]
]
```

if found this (http://phpjs.org/functions/array_merge_recursive/), what doesent work for me since it just pushes the arrays together

my idea was to go torugh both array recursive and check the values
and if they match i would push the childrens of the other to the index of the matching val.

But i have no idea how to start or even end this

thx guys

for explaination

```
var komands = [];
kmd('add,image,to,title,published');
kmd('add,text,to,title,published');
function kmd(kmd){
    komand = [];
    kmnd = kmd.split(',').reverse();
    function pusher(value, obj){obj[1]=value;return [obj.reverse()];}
    $.each(kmnd,function(i,val){
        komand = pusher(val, komand);
    });
    komands = !!!! array_merge_recursive(komands, komand); !!!!
    console.log(komands);
}
```

I wrote that function with which i can archive to have a large tree structure of custom commands within seconds.
The only problem is that i cant merge the single array into one atm.
Thats why i asked

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: @Archer thx for this wise answer, Maybe one can archive this with plain js, but its definelty a jquery related question, since im workin explicit in js atm. So next time maybe just dont pust such a comment

Comment: if you control the structure of initial data it sure seems like you would be better off using objects instead of arrays

Comment: will i be still able to push them into eachother, like i do now?

Answer (score 0):

the elegant solution is this.
Im using objects instead of arrays and extending them with a deep copy
thx for the suggestions

```
var komands = {};
kmd('add,image,to,published(),execute');
kmd('add,image,to,unpublished(),execute');
function kmd(kmd){
    komand = {};
    function pusher(v,oj){o={};o[v]=oj;return o;}
    $.each(kmd.split(',').reverse(),function(i,v){komand = pusher(v,komand)});
    $.extend(true,komands,komand);
}
console.log(komands)
```